# Update Angular2 to latest version

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to update Angular2 to the latest version release candidate 4.

I have executed *npm outdated* and edited accordingly the package.json file.
Then I have executed *npm update* which failed. I haven't saved the error message. In the following I googled and tried several different npm commands. Unfortunately I cannot recall them.

The current status is, that *npm update* does not show anything; so seems to work.
The command *npm start* starts the server, but the browser console displays multiple errors. The first is:

```
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Besides *npm install* shows the following warnings:

```
typings WARN deprecated 2016-06-02: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 2016-06-22: "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 2016-06-22: "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

├── core-js (global)
├── jasmine (global)
└── node (global)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /lite-server/browser-sync/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
```

The package.json relevant parts are currently:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.9",
    "systemjs": "0.19.31",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
```

Comment: did you successfully remove previous version?

Comment: No, I thought that the previous version is removed automatically, when I update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. Take latest package.json from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart
3. Run 'npm install' command.

Comment: This exactly has not worked for me. But inspired by this I copied the package.json and systemjs.config from https://github.com/angular/quickstart. Thanks.

Comment: `systemjs` has the configuration for your node_modules so it might have been the case that you needed to update your system.config.ts

Comment: worekd for me also, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In typings.json one must update to new registry value, if problem shows up for core-js

> "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654"

to

> "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759"

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/commit/8a8c64e0e8b18cd0c19c1ab2f1dc71a30bbd6174

Comment: How do you identify which is the correct version to update to and track? (I would like to apply same principal to node and core-js and potentially others)

Answer (score 1):

This might be outdated but your typings were never addressed. Given that you would want to always keep them up to date. Also for anyone else seeking to know about the update process

Here is how you could update/reinstall them

Example:
For your *node* to update it simply type

```
typings install dt~node --save --global
```

The following will update your node typings which would be in `/typings/global/node`

If you did not have node the same command would suffice and your `index.d.ts` will also be update with a new entry!